# Classe StreamWriter

Tags: c#, io

Minha ideia é criar um sistema para inserir novos funcionários através do método `CadastrarFuncionario()`, colocando as propriedades da classe (`ID, nome, CPF`) dentro de um arquivo de nome funcionarios.txt.

Com a lógica utilizada por mim, os valores são inseridos com sucesso no arquivo. Entretanto, se eu desejo cadastrar um novo funcionário após ter registrado um, os dados são sobrescritos e não adicionados após pular uma linha.

Segue aqui o meu código:

```
    public static void CadastrarFuncionario()
    {          
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream(String.Format(@"C:\Files\funcionarios.txt"), FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
        {
            Funcionario f = new Funcionario();

            Console.WriteLine("ID: ");
            f.id = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("Nome: ");
            f.nome = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("CPF: ");
            f.cpf = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


            streamWriter.WriteLine("ID: " + f.id);
            streamWriter.WriteLine("Nome: " + f.nome);
            streamWriter.WriteLine("CPF: " + f.cpf);
            streamWriter.WriteLine("");

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a configuração do segundo parâmetro para fazer isso e retire, então, [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.90).aspx), exemplo:

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Temp\funcionarios.txt", true))
{

}
```

***ou***

adicione [FileMode.Append](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx) no [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.90).aspx)

```
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\Temp\funcionarios.txt", FileMode.Append))
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream))
{

}
```

***Observação:*** *no caso da pergunta, utilize a segunda maneira, mas, vale lembrar que não é necessário e o seu código pode ser resumido com a primeira opção*

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [Classe StreamWriter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.streamwriter(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Enumeração FileMode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filemode(v=vs.110).aspx)
- [Classe FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.filestream(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

no seu `StreamWriter` você pode inicializar com o parâmetro `Append` como true:

```
 TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter("arquivo.txt", true, Encoding.Default);
```

Para o `Encoding.Default` é necessário `using System.Text;`

Comment: Está sendo apontado erro no true: "Não é possível converter de "bool" para "System.Text.Encoding" e também "Encoding não contém uma definição para Default"

Comment: é só a variação da sobrecarga, porque você está usando um stream, e eu uma string. Faça como Virgilio mostrou